# How to move inter-dependent objects together and maintain internal references

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to write the move constructor for a class that has two move-only members.  The difficulty is that one of the members holds a reference to the other, so once they are both moved, one of the members refers to an object that no longer exists:

```
class Server : noncopyable
{
};

class Client : noncopyable
{
public:
    Client(Server& server) : server_(server) {}
    Client(Client&& other) : server_(std::move(other.server_)) {}

    std::reference_wraper<Server> server_;
};

class MyClass : noncopyable
{
public:
    MyClass() 
       : server_(),
         client_(server_) {}

    // destroys other.server_ which client uses before and after move
    MyClass(MyClass&& other)
       : server_(std::move(other.server_)),
         client_(std::move(other.client_))

private:
    Server server_;
    Client client_;
};
```

Is there a good way to handle this kind of situation?  Basically the referencing object needs its reference updating to the moved-to version when it is itself moved.

Comment: I would have thought that the `client_` (in the move case) would be constructed with the new `server_`? So it would be `client_(server_)`? btw. you don't need to do `server_(Server())`, if you want to default construct, it should be `server_()` and for client `client_(server_)`, else you'll trigger the move constructor for both when `MyClass` is default constructed..

Comment: @Nim In this case, that would actually work but what about more generally when the client has state that needs to still be present accross the move?

Comment: @Nim Fixed the typos.  Thanks for spotting.

Comment: Anyway, this is wrong -> `Client(Server&& other)`, it should be `Client(Client&& other)`, but even then you cannot do this correctly! In the new instance of `MyClass`, you have a *new instance* of `server_`, so you need to register this with the `client_`, you cannot do this using a simple move! You need a constructor that takes explicitly the new `server_` instance and allows you to move the other stuff out of the other client, i.e. `Client(Server& server, Client&& other)`, now you have a new server instance, and you can move other stuff you need out of the other Client instance?

Comment: Using pointers to Client/Server would significantly simplify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to kiss the value members of `MyClass` goodbye.

If you simply use `std::unique_ptr<Server>` and `std::unique_ptr<Client>` here instead, the rest comes quite naturally - as the `Server` object itself is never moved, but only the pointer to it held by `MyClass`, you don't need to update anything in `Client`.

Comment: That works.  Thanks. FWIW, I'm using `auto_ptr` because I'm actually on C++03 with Boost.Move emulation.